# Feature Upgrade Retract Deploy Power Shell Commands

Tags: 2010, powershell, feature, feature-upgrade

I have heard that one way that you can upgrade a feature in SharePoint with new files is to do a retract deploy. I believe this is what Visual Studio 2010 does when you do a Deploy. What are the Power Shell commands to-do a retract deploy?

Answer (score 2):

Chris O'Brien have a [good topics](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/06/feature-upgrade-part-1-fundamentals.html) that describes how to update feature correctly. Also he provided a tool that can help you to do it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for powershell commands to retract\deploy you need this:

**Deploy**:

- [Add-SPSolution](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607552.aspx)
- [Install-SPSolution](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607534.aspx)
- [Enable-SPFeature](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607803.aspx)

**Retract**:

- [Disable-SPFeature](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607879.aspx)
- [Uninstall-SPSolution](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607873.aspx)
- [Remove-SPSolution](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607748.aspx)

But your tags a little bit confusing..